# Reading combination of string and double from file

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io

I'm looking for an efficient and non-hacky way to read a bunch of data from a text file. I have a class called Information, which holds 3 private variables:

```
string location;
double latitude;
double longitude;
```

The format of the input will be a huge text file with each line formatted as below:

```
34.3153920 66.7239403 Seattle
```

I have already tried going a few routes.

1. I tried to read it in line by line and parse it in the Information constructor, but the stod() function was truncating my data. It would read something like 34.3153 and 66.7239.

I also attempted to read it in with a space delimiter via getline(ss, line, ' ') but this was not working either.

I am **not** asking for anyone to write code for me, but is there a simple way that I am missing to map these 3 fields to my Information object without having to get hacky with a parser?

Any feedback is appreciated, thanks!

**The stod did not, in fact, truncate my data. The truncation came from the precision (or lack thereof) in my cout statements.**

Comment: `the stod() function was truncating my data` are you sure this isn't a question of the [precision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) of the output stream? How did you verify that the data was truncated?

Comment: Thanks @user657267 I made a very careless mistake not realizing that. I will resolve this question.

Comment: Do you still need an answer on this?

Comment: I do not, I am not too sure how to mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem which was actually that my cout statements were influencing the precision of my double values!